# Twilio chat client channels list

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to create a simple chat app between 2 users, using twilio js api.

The idea is that I know that two users will have to chat with each other, and I want to create a channel specifically for the chat between them both.
So when a user logs in, I want to search the channel by it's name:

- if it exist already, it means that the other user is already logged, and I want to join this channel.
- else, I want to create a channel by this specific name, and wait for the other user.

I tried 2 alternatives:
 1. chat client.
 2. IPMessaging client.

I am trying to user this function:

```
chatClient.getChannels().then(function (channels){ // search for the channel I need // }
```

But for chat channel I get the following error:

```
twilio TypeError: chatClient.getChannels is not a function
```

So with an IPMessaging client it all works well, but I can't trigger events of user typing, which are important for my app:

```
chatChannel.on('typingStarted', function(){
    console.log('user started typing')
});
chatChannel.on('typingEnded', function(){
    console.log('user stopped typing')
});
```

Should this events be possible to trigger for IPMessaging Client?
If not, how can I get the channels list for a chat client?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger typing indicators with IPMessaging (Programmable chat): 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/typing-indicator

```
//intercept the keydown event
inputBox.on('keydown', function(e) {
    //if the RETURN/ENTER key is pressed, send the message
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
        sendButton.click(); 
    }
    //else send the Typing Indicator signal
    else { 
        activeChannel.typing(); 
    }
});
```

That same event can be triggered for members, and not only channels. 
https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.11.1/docs/Member.html